# Keeping track of multiple buttons and how many each have been clicked

Tags: javascript

I have multiple clickable element in my html and would like to keep track of how many times each respective button have been clicked. 
I could do a very inelegant solution which would consist of having a specific function for each button such as function button1(), function button2(), etc... called by an onclick but I am sure there is a better way of doing this. 
Thank you for your help.

```
<div class="starter">
        <h3>Starter</h3>
        <div class="starterItems">
            <button type="button" id="salmon" >Salmon Tartare with fresh diced tomatoes</button>
            <button type="button" id="prawn" >Prawn Cocktail with homemade marrinade</button>
            <button type="button" id="soup">Asparagus Soup served with croutons</button>
        </div>
</div>


var salmon = document.getElementById('salmon'), 
prawn = document.getElementById('prawn'),
soup = document.getElementById('soup'),
clicks = {}; 

function click(e){
var id = e.target.id; 
if(!clicks[id])
    clicks[id]=0;
clicks[id]++;
e.target.textContent = clicks[id];
}

salmon.addEventListener('click', click); 
prawn.addEventListener('click', click); 
soup.addEventListener('click', click);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using the id of the element as keys:

```js
var b1 = document.getElementById('b1'),
  b2 = document.getElementById('b2'),
  b3 = document.getElementById('b3'),
  clicks = {};

function click(e) {
  var id = e.target.id;
  if (!clicks[id])
    clicks[id] = 0;
  clicks[id]++;
  e.target.textContent = clicks[id];
}

b1.addEventListener('click', click);
b2.addEventListener('click', click);
b3.addEventListener('click', click);
```

```html
<button id="b1">Button 1</button>
<button id="b2">Button 2</button>
<button id="b3">Button 3</button>
```

---

### Using a `data-` attribute:

```js
var b1 = document.getElementById('b1'),
  b2 = document.getElementById('b2'),
  b3 = document.getElementById('b3');

function click(e) {
  if (!e.target.getAttribute('data-clicks'))
    e.target.setAttribute('data-clicks', 0);
  var clicks = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-clicks'));
  e.target.setAttribute('data-clicks', clicks + 1);
  e.target.textContent = clicks + 1;
}

b1.addEventListener('click', click);
b2.addEventListener('click', click);
b3.addEventListener('click', click);
```

```html
<button id="b1">Button 1</button>
<button id="b2">Button 2</button>
<button id="b3">Button 3</button>
```

---

And, as others have mentioned, using `localStorage` is a valid option as well. The implementation would be something like using the id as a key above.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am however getting a strange behaviour. The counter records more click than I physically do. Maybe it is because my buttons are wrapped within a div, what do you think?

Comment: @SangamChouchan You'll have to elaborate; I don't experience the behavior you're describing. Please show your code in your question.

Comment: added the code im working with. Thank you again for helping, i appreciate.

Comment: @SangamChouchan Working fine. Do note that `e.target.textContent = clicks[id];` is just for demonstration purposes. `clicks[id]` holds the number of clicks. Happy Coding!

Comment: @SangamChouchan Explain

Comment: as i said. after clicking on the button the counter is added to +1, but after i wait for a few moments, the counter keep increasing on its own without me doing any clicks...

Comment: that s really weird...i copied and pasted exactly the same html, css, and javascript code in jsfiddle and everything is fine. Not when I check on my localhost, any thoughts on why this could be possible?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your existing code base. One simple approach is to have an identifier for all the buttons you want to keep track of, for example a class. Then you would simply bind and event for that specific class. As simple as that.

For the sake of an example, for each button (or any other element, it doesn't really matter) we will pick the following attribute as our identifier: `data-count-clicks`. In order to give them an identity, the aforementioned identifier will also have an optional value. For example we will have something like this `data-count-clicks="salmon"` or `data-count-clicks="prawn"`.

This works with dynamic generated elements (don't forget to check the console logs):

```js
(function() {
  var counter = {};

  document.addEventListener('click', onClickFn);

  function onClickFn(event) {
    var el = event.target;

    while (el) {
      if (matches(el, '[data-count-clicks]')) {
        var elemName = el.getAttribute('data-count-clicks') || 'nameless';

        if (typeof counter[elemName] === 'number') {
          counter[elemName] += 1;
        } else {
          counter[elemName] = 1;
        }

        console.log(counter);
      }

      el = el.parentElement;
    }
  }

  // Polyfill for element.matches
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches
  function matches(elm, selector) {
    var matches = (elm.document || elm.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(selector),
      i = matches.length;

    while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== elm);

    return i > -1;
  }
})();
```

```html
<body>
  <button data-count-clicks="salmon">salmon</button>
  <button data-count-clicks="prawn">prawn</button>
  <button data-count-clicks="soup">soup</button>
  <button data-count-clicks>no name</button>
  <button data-count-clicks>no name</button>

  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, quisquam!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque nostrum repellendus consectetur, doloribus eaque nobis rerum minima aut porro ducimus possimus eligendi <strong data-count-clicks="strong-tag">you can also click me</strong> expedita corrupti,
      ut vero atque ratione fugiat itaque, voluptatum. Quidem, ullam.</p>
    <p data-count-clicks="nested--parent"><strong data-count-clicks="nested--child">nested clicks</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

A simpler solution which doesn't works with dynamic generated elements (don't forget to check the console logs):

```js
(function() {
  var counter = {};

  var clickElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-count-clicks]');

  for (var i = 0; i < clickElements.length; i++) {
    clickElements[i].addEventListener('click', onClickFn);
  }

  function onClickFn() {
    var elemName = this.getAttribute('data-count-clicks') || 'nameless';

    if (typeof counter[elemName] === 'number') {
      counter[elemName] += 1;

    } else {
      counter[elemName] = 1;
    }

    console.log(counter);
  }
})();
```

```html
<body>
  <button data-count-clicks="salmon">salmon</button>
  <button data-count-clicks="prawn">prawn</button>
  <button data-count-clicks="soup">soup</button>
  <button data-count-clicks>no name</button>
  <button data-count-clicks>no name</button>

  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, quisquam!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque nostrum repellendus consectetur, doloribus eaque nobis rerum minima aut porro ducimus possimus eligendi <strong data-count-clicks="strong-tag">you can also click me</strong> expedita corrupti,
      ut vero atque ratione fugiat itaque, voluptatum. Quidem, ullam.</p>
    <p data-count-clicks="nested--parent"><strong data-count-clicks="nested--child">nested clicks</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I would like to know more about data binding if possible. thanks.

Comment: @SangamChouchan sure, see my example.

Answer (score 1):

The elegant solution would be to use `localStorage or sessionStorage` dependening upon your need.

```
var count = 0;
function yourFunction(e) {        
    count= parseInt(count) + parseInt(1); 
    localStorage['button1'] = count; OR
    localStorage[e.target.id] = count; OR 
}
```

You could surely improve the code by getting the `id of the button` instead of 'button1', setting this in the `localStorage` and getting it next time would be the easier way. Infact if you would like you can persist an object too in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same css class to each of your buttons and assign the same function to all of them. (Note that you need jQuery for that.)

```
$(".myClass").on("click", function(event){

  var clickedButtonId = event.target.id;

  // here you have id of the button that is clicked, and you can do whatever you want with that id

});
```

The function is defined only once, and it serves all your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something in jQuery like

js:

```
 $('.button').on('click', function(){
      $(this).attr('data-counter', parseInt($(this).attr('data-counter') + 1) );
 });
```

html:

```
<button class="button" data-counter="0"></button>
```

And doing that you would have every counter in data-counter attr, separately.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object and and a counter for each button to it e.g.:

```
var buttonClicks = {};
```

In the handler for each button click, make a call to a function which updates this object for you. e.g.

```
function incrementButtonCounter(buttonId) {
    if (typeof buttonClicks[buttonId] === 'undefined') {
          buttonClicks[buttonId] = 1;
          return;
    }

    buttonClicks[buttonId]++;
}
```

Make sure the `incrementButtonCounter` function can see the `buttonClicks` object ie they have to be in the same namespace - preferably not the global.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an object with count data for each bata.

```
var count = {
  'btn1': 0,
  'btn2': 0,
  'btn3': 0
}
```

and increment the fields when the buttons are clicked.

```
function handle(item) {
  var clickedBtnId = item.target.getAttribute('id');
  count[clickedBtnId]++;
  update();
}

function update() {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Btn 1 ' + count.btn1 + ' clicks <br/>' +
    'Btn 2 ' + count.btn2 + ' clicks <br/> ' +
    'Btn 3 ' + count.btn3 + ' clicks';
}

var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
var btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3');

btn1.onclick = handle;
btn2.onclick = handle;
btn3.onclick = handle;
```

[Working example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnfvnjf0/1/)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```js
 var buttons = {};

 function handleBtnClick(btnName) {
   buttons[btnName] = (buttons[btnName] || 0) + 1;
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="handleBtnClick('muFirstButton')">my button 1</button>
<button onclick="handleBtnClick('muSecondButton')">my button 2</button>
```